# Removing logical volume without confirmation

Tags: scripting, lvm

I'm writing an automated script that will remove a logical volume, but I'm not 100% sure how to do this. It looks like one should use the `-f` flag to `lvremove`, but the documentation seem too sloppy to make me comfortable with that:

> -f|--force ...
>
> Override various checks, confirmations and protections.  Use with extreme caution.

What are those "various checks, confirmations and protections"? To me it seems that there's a risk I'm sidestepping something else than just the confirmation about deleting the volume.

Answer (score 1):

I think your biggest risk is to remove a volume that is still in use somehow. I.e. if `dmsetup info` shows a non-zero `Open count`.

```
# dmsetup info SSD-root | grep Open
Open count:        1
```

However in this case `lvremove` will straight up refuse to operate.

```
# lvremove SSD/root
  Logical volume SSD/root contains a filesystem in use.
```

Even with `--force` it still refuses to delete it (don't try this at home).

```
# lvremove --force --yes --verbose SSD/root
    Device dm-33 (253:33) appears to be mounted on /.
  Logical volume SSD/root contains a filesystem in use.
```

This even works if not mounted, just in use otherwise.

```
# lvcreate -n test -L100M SSD
# losetup --find --show /dev/SSD/test
# time lvremove SSD/test
  Logical volume SSD/test is in use.
real    0m4.816s
user    0m0.008s
sys 0m0.005s
```

Actually this is very slow (5 seconds for this lvremove call!) since it looks for mountpoint everywhere, doesn't find one, and keeps re-checking the open count. So it's like "huh this isn't mounted so why still open".

So for regular volumes, I think it's reasonably safe to use `--force` here; it doesn't force cases that are actually dangerous. The manpage even suggests the use of force in the Examples section. However, I haven't tested what happens in case of snapshot, cache and otherwise special volumes.

Answer (score 0):

The man page for `lvremove` also offers `--yes`, which states

> Do not prompt for confirmation interactively but always assume the answer yes.

This should allow you to avoid having to use `--force` (with all its unspecified checks and balances) while still being able to have the volume removed programmatically.

(I know I've not addressed the protections that `--force` removes. I have offered an alternative that I believe will address your underlying requirement. Don't feel you have to accept this answer if you actually want to know about `--force`.)

Comment: Unfortunately that has the same disadvantage, perhaps to a lesser degree but still. It assumes the answer `yes` to any unspecified confirmation. Can I be sure that the only question asked is whether I should remove the specified volume? Or could it happen that some other (unexpected) question is asked?